How to re-render only child component if parent child share same state variable in React
I have parent with multiple children, I want to only re-render selected children, not parent component over and over.
const ParentComp = () =>
{
    const [state1, setState1] = useState(0);
    const [state2, setState2] = useState(0);
    const [state3, setState3] = useState(0);
    // ... more children if needed

    // example: do something complex based on events
    //          and update states for desired component

    return(
        // ... parent stuff
        <ChildComp1 state=state1/>
        <ChildComp1 state=state2/>
        <ChildComp1 state=state3/>
        // ... parent stuff
    )
}

I can wrap children in memo and it will render selected child component but it will still re-render parent.

If ParentComp has to pass some props to ChildComp1, you pretty much have to update ParentComp. If ChildComp1 can fetch it's state determining values internally, then you can make use of forceUpdate - which is not an encouraged practice.

I explored React further and you are absolutely right. Thanks for your help.

what about something like this:
import React, { useState, useCallback, memo } from 'react';

const ChildComp1 = memo(({ state }) => {
  console.log("ChildComp1 state:", state);
  return <div>{state}</div>;
});


Yes, thanks, this works; however, parent still re-renders. I looked into react a bit more and what @hn719 said in comment makes perfect sense. I'm new to react, thanks for your effort

No problem thx to you
